# Перенос элементов из символьного массива в двумерный массив

Tags: c++, c, массивы, char

Есть массив `s[]` типа `char`, в котором  содержится некий текст.  Как перенести слова из массива `s[]` в массив `T1["номер слова"]["элементы слова"]`. Желательно на C; в крайнем случае - C++.

Comment: C и C++ - два разных языка. Поэтому укажите точно, какой язык вас интересует.

Comment: желательно с  но можно и с++

Comment: нужен с   но могу понять на с++  и переелать под с

Comment: Вы не сможете переписать код с C++ на C, так как в C++ могут использоваться средства, как, например, стандартные контейнеры, которые отсутствуют в C.

Comment: мне надо попроще  и на с

Answer (score 3):

Если считать разделителем whitespace, т.е. считать "словами" то, что считает словами спецификатор формата `%s` в `scanf`, то можно воспользоваться `sscanf` и выстроить структуру, аналогичную `char *argv[]`

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **split_words(const char *s)
{
  assert(s != NULL);    

  size_t n_words = 0, n_words_mem = 0;  

  size_t n_lead, n_word;
  for (const char *p = s; 
       sscanf(p, " %zn%*s%zn", &n_lead, &n_word) == 0 && *(p + n_lead) != '\0'; 
       p += n_word)
  {
    assert(n_lead < n_word);
    ++n_words;
    n_words_mem += n_word - n_lead + 1;
  }

  if (n_words == 0)
    return NULL;

  char **words = malloc((n_words + 1) * sizeof *words);

  assert(n_words_mem > 0);
  char *words_mem = malloc(n_words_mem);

  if (words == NULL || words_mem == NULL)
  {
    free(words);
    free(words_mem);
    return NULL;
  }

  size_t i_word = 0;
  char *word = words_mem;
  for (const char *p = s; 
       sscanf(p, " %zn%s%zn", &n_lead, word, &n_word) == 1 && *(p + n_lead) != '\0'; 
       p += n_word, ++i_word, word += n_word - n_lead + 1)
  {
    assert(i_word < n_words);
    assert(word < words_mem + n_words_mem);
    assert(n_lead < n_word && strlen(word) == n_word - n_lead);
    words[i_word] = word;
  }

  assert(i_word == n_words);
  assert(word == words_mem + n_words_mem);

  words[i_word] = NULL;

  return words;  
}


int main(void) 
{
  char **words = split_words(" Mama   myla raammu  ");
  for (char **pword = words; *pword != NULL; ++pword)
    printf("'%s'\n", *pword);
}
```

Устраивает ли вас такая структура в качестве результирующего двумерного массива - вам виднее. Ибо деталями ваша постановка вопроса не особо богата.

Answer (score 2):

Вот решение на C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#define SIZE(array) sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])

const char* word(const char *begin, const char *end){
    static const char separators[] = " ,.";

    return std::find_first_of(begin, end, separators, separators + SIZE(separators));
}

int main()
{
    char text[] = "What is your name?";
    char words[5][5] = {0};

    const char *begin = text;
    const char *end = text + SIZE(text);

    for(int i = 0; begin < end; ++i){
        const char *pos = word(begin, end);
        std::copy(begin, pos, &words[i][0]);
        begin = pos + 1;        
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j){
            std::cout << words[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[std::find_first_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_first_of/)
[std::copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/)

Answer (score 2):

Решение на С с использованием библиотеки [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.48/)

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <glib/gprintf.h>

#define MAX_TOKEN    10
int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
  int i;
  char text[] = "What is your name?";
  char ** words = NULL;
  words = g_strsplit(text," ",MAX_TOKEN); 

  for(i = 0;i < MAX_TOKEN;i++){
    char * w = words[i];
    if(w == NULL){
      break;
    }
    g_printf("word[%d] :> %s\n",w);
  }

  g_strfreev(words); 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот готовый код для подобной задачи. Разделяет строку на двумерный массив слов, как вам и нужно. Работает с выделением памяти, по-другому никак.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int     calc_nb_words(char *str, int *size_word)//считает кол-во слов в строке через пробелы и табуляции
{
    int word;
    int i;

    i = 0;
    word = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ')
            word++;
        while (str[i] != ' ')
        {
            size_word[word - 1] = size_word[word - 1] + 1;
            i++;
        }
        while (str[i] == ' ')
            i++;
    }
    return (word);
}

void    ft_split_whitespaces(char *str)//разносит слова в "строки" двумерного массива
{
    int     nb_words;
    int     tab[10];
    char    *temp;
    char    **string;
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    nb_words = calc_nb_words(str, tab);
    *string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(**string) * (nb_words + 1));
    while (i < nb_words)
    {
        string[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(*temp) * (tab[i] + 1));
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ft_split_whitespaces("Hello world");
    return 0;
}
```